# Want to re-tweet with a message using Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am creating a twitter bot with Python to retweet to any mention with a message. Below is the part of code that I am using to retweet:

```
twitter_client = API(auth_handler)
    publish = True
    if publish:
        # print(data)
        twitter_client.retweet(tweet['id'])
```

This is doing retweet correctly, but I am not sure which field (from **on_data**) to use so that my retweet goes with a message like "Thanks for your mention, we are happy to serve you"

Answer (score 0):

Retweet allows only to tweet the same content. You can use reply to that tweet['id'] and send your message "Thanks for your mention, we are happy to serve you". Reply takes a text field as parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out.
Just sharing the solution hopefully it may help in future:
api.update_status(status=repl_msg)

where repl_msg is the variable that will store the message that we need to send.